# GPG key pair generation: What do the plus and minus signs mean?

Tags: gpg

I just generated a new GPG key pair and gpg displays some random plus, minus, greater than, less than and circumflex signs. I was always wondering what they mean. Can you explain it to me?

```
iblue@nerdpol:~$ gpg --gen-key
[... snip ...]

We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
.........+++............<+++++>.+++++...............>..+++++..<
...+++++............>+++++<.+++++.....................<+++++..>
.................................................+++++^^^^
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are progress indications from the key generation process. Since key generation can be slow, you get a bit of an animated display. The details of the display are pretty obscure and not useful except (a little) for debugging some very specific part of GPG.

You're seeing an [El Gamal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Gamal) key pair generation. GPG needs to generate several numbers with specific mathematical properties. Some of these numbers, for example prime numbers, are generated by trial and error (generate a random number in approximately the right range, test if it has the requisite properties, req). GPG print:

- a newline after successfully generating a prime or generator;
- `<` and `>` if a randomly generated prime is rejected for not being in the proper range;
- `!` if a prime is rejected for not being suitable after all;
- `^` when trying a candidate generator;
- `.` if a randomly generated candidate prime *p* turns out not to be prime and GPG tries *p*+2;
- `:` if a randomly generated candidate prime turns out not to be prime and GPG tries a fresh random number;
- `.` if a simple primality test fails;
- `+` if a long primality test succeeds.

If you want the detailed list, look at calls to `progress` in `cipher/dsa.c`, `cipher/elgamal.c` and `cipher/primegen.c` in the GPG source.